# Use <glyph> as 'background-image', taken from a single SVG

Tags: css, svg, icons, background-image, glyphicons

I know that I can use a single *SVG* file per-icon and then use it as `background-image` with:

```
.my-button {
    background-image: url(binaries/icons/my-icon.svg);
}
```

### or

that I can have the glyphs defined with an *unicode* value and then add it in my styles relying on the `content` applied in a *:after/:before pseudo-element*, like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <font id="fontello" horiz-adv-x="1000" >
            <font-face font-family="fontello" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" units-per-em="1000" ascent="850" descent="-150" />
            <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="1000" />
            <glyph glyph-name="my-icon unicode="&#xe800;" d="m564 422l-234-224q-18-18-40-18t-40 18l-234 224q-16 16-16 41t16 41q38 38 78 0l196-188 196 188q40 38 78 0 16-16 16-41t-16-41z" horiz-adv-x="580" />
            <glyph glyph-name="up-open" unicode="&#xe805;" d="m564 280q16-16 16-41t-16-41q-38-38-78 0l-196 188-196-188q-40-38-78 0-16 16-16 41t16 41l234 224q16 16 40 16t40-16z" horiz-adv-x="580" />
        </font>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

and then having a base class plus a decorator class for the specific icon, like this:

```
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'fontello';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    ...
}

.glyphicon__my-iconn:before {
    content: "\e800";
}
```

### But

I was wondering if would it be possible to directly reference a glyph in a single SVG file, probably with an absolute/relative path, and use it as **backgound-image url()**, without defining an additional class but just applying the style to my desired one (*my-button* in this case). Something like (just an example, I don't know what the right URI format should be):

```
.my-button {
    background-image: url(binaries/icons/my-fontello-font.svg?font=fontello#my-icon
}
```

This would be perfect to:

- have just one single HTTP request when loading glyph-icons
- skip the definition of a single class for every single icon (what if I have 200 icons??) and just use them

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

Answer (score 1):

I've had a brief dig through the topic (was searching for it and found that question). From what I've found out, there could be a way to do it, but it has lacks in browser support.

What I think of is having a little parser (like a simple grunt task) that would change glyphs into views and paths and then use them as described here: https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work (background-image method).

Hope that could guide you somewhere. I'll probably dig this topic a bit further, but so far it only seems to be possible that way (so not in every browser).

Comment: U R right. I also found that way and, even if it has advantages (big companies use this), I personally didn't like much the approach.
In the end I surrendered to create multiple classes or play with some smart SCSS mixin. And atm I just pass the name of the icon, defined in the SVG, to my mixin (so, no unclear HTML entities, or charachters that change from release to release of my SVG icon set).
For now is a fair solution that suits my  needs (something quickly maintainable, with support for CSS colored icons). But I hope in further support of a way to query a single glyph in a SVG-XML file.